# Can numbers be represented as lines?

Tags: plotting

Does this make sense? The place values of a number can be translated into a y axis intercept
and with selected slope a number can represented as line.

```
 p1 = Plot[
   Flatten[100 Range[IntegerLength[30101]] + 
      15 Range[IntegerDigits[30101]]] + x, {x, 0, 500}];
 p2 = Plot[
   100 Flatten[Position[IntegerDigits[3010], 0]] + x, {x, 0, 500}, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashed];
 Show[{p1, p2}]
```

Comment: Is this a software/programming issue or math?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is nor what your plots are meant to represent. Please provide additional background to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply to my first post.